# Sum up array values if array keys are the same in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have been messing around with this for really long time but couldn't find a way of doing it. Any help will be much appreciated!

So I have the following array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 113
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 69
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 39
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 38
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 24
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPad
        [occurrences] => 23
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 19
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => iPhone
        [occurrences] => 12
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => Windows
        [occurrences] => 4
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [user_agent] => Macintosh
        [occurrences] => 3
    )
```

Desired result is something like:

```
Array 
(
   [user_agent]=>iPhone
   [occurrences] => //numbers added from old array where user agent is iPhone..

   .. so on with all different user_agents
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: have you tried something

Comment: foreach fill a new array with user_agent value as key and occurrences as value, if exists add otherwise set to the value

Comment: That is a REALLY simple problem, if you can't solve it you should take a algorithm course ASAP. Also @hellcode gave you the a good solution to the problem...

Comment: I think this question needs to be closed as OP is not showing any effort over here @Rizier123

Answer (score 0):

```
$userAgentOccurrenceCountsSourceData = [
    [
        'user_agent' => 'iPhone',
        'occurrences' => 113,
    ],
    // …
];

$userAgentOccurrenceCounts = [];

foreach ($userAgentOccurrenceCountsSourceData as $userAgentOccurrenceCount) {
    $userAgent = $userAgentOccurrenceCount['user_agent'];

    if(!isset($userAgentOccurrenceCounts[$userAgent])) {
        $userAgentOccurrenceCounts[$userAgent] = 0;
    }

    $userAgentOccurrenceCounts[$userAgent] += $userAgentOccurrenceCount['occurrences'];
}
```