# PHP Sum values if the object has the same key in a array whilst carrying the remaining data unchanged

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

> **Note:** The following question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118526/sum-up-array-values-if-array-keys-are-the-same-in-php), but I need more context for my answer.

I have an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => VAT
            [tax_amount] => 3.000
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 15.44
            [price_includes_tax] => Y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => VAT
            [tax_amount] => 3.000
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 59.68
            [price_includes_tax] => Y
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => VAT
            [tax_amount] => 3.000
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 1.86
            [price_includes_tax] => Y
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => GST
            [tax_amount] => 3.300
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 2.11
            [price_includes_tax] => N
        )

)
```

and I want the output like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => VAT
            [tax_amount] => 3.000
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 76.98
            [price_includes_tax] => Y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => GST
            [tax_amount] => 3.300
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 2.11
            [price_includes_tax] => N
        )

)
```

The following code solves my problem partially

```
$result = [];

    array_walk($_tax_array, function($item) use (&$result) {
        if (!isset($result[$item['tax_name']])) {
            $result[$item['tax_name']] = 0;
        }

        $result[$item['tax_name']] += $item['tax_price'];
    });
    
    $resultFormated = [];
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $resultFormated[] = ['tax_name' => $key, 'tax_price' => $value];
    }

    print_r($resultFormated);
```

If I run this code I get the output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => VAT
            [tax_price] => 76.98
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => GST
            [tax_price] => 2.11
        )

)
```

My problem is I don't know how to carry the remaining datas such as `tax_amount`, `tax_type` & `price_includes_tax` without affecting the result.

Comment: If you want unique values for tax amount, tax type and price_includes_tax then you must not group by tax_name only. You then have to group by all columns except tax_price. Each column must either be aggregated (e.g. summed) or grouped.

Comment: Yes, I understood my mistake and corrected in the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for sometime I have finally figured out the answer. Here is the answer

```
$tax_array = array();
foreach ($_tax_array as $array) {
$type= false;
foreach ($tax_array as $pos => $temp_array) {
    if(
        $temp_array['tax_name'] == $array['tax_name']){
        $tax_array[$pos]['tax_price'] += $array['tax_price'];
        $type= true;
    }
}
if(!$type) {
    $tax_array[] = array(
        'tax_name' => $array['tax_name'], 
        'tax_type' => $array['tax_type'], 
        'tax_price' => $array['tax_price'],
        'tax_amount' => $array['tax_amount'],
        'price_includes_tax' => $array['price_includes_tax'],
        );
    }
}
print_r($tax_array);
```

This code solves my problem. This code outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => VAT
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 76.98
            [tax_amount] => 3.000
            [price_includes_tax] => Y
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tax_name] => GST
            [tax_type] => P
            [tax_price] => 2.11
            [tax_amount] => 3.300
            [price_includes_tax] => N
        )
```